# Invalid Syntax in build.py

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I'm trying to build an application using this - https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-rekognition-video-analyzer/
Unfortunately, i'm getting a syntaxerror in the build.py file.

```
def write_dir_to_zip(src, zf):
'''Write a directory tree to an open ZipFile object.'''
abs_src = os.path.abspath(src)
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for filename in files:
        absname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
        arcname = absname[len(abs_src) + 1:]
        print 'zipping %s as %s' % (os.path.join(dirname, filename),
                                    arcname)
        zf.write(absname, arcname)
```

The error i'm getting is as follows

```
 File "build.py", line 26
 arcname)) zf.write(absname, arcname)
          ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message does not match the source code. the error shows two )) after arcname, but your source shows one ).